# Customizing QTreeWidget's child indicator

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I have implemented a custom child indicator for a `QTreeWidget` as a `QPushButton` and still in the process of making it look like the original. My question is if anyone knows what control does `Qt` use for the child indicator, or is it some other control, like a customized `QLabel?` I have implemented it by sub-classing `QPushButton` with `QPushButton::setFlat(true)` and `QPushButton::setCheckable(true).` But I still see the inflate/deflate behavior of the control when I click on it, just like it happens with `QPushButton.` So, should I continue styling the button until I get the desired behavior, or should I sub-class another `Qt` widget instead?

Here's the screenshot of a typical `QTreeWidget` with a child indicator. I want to know what control does `Qt` use for it:

[image]

Comment: I think you just need to style it, see [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html). "The ::branch Sub-control supports the :open, :closed, :has-sibling and :has-children pseudo states."

Comment: Also just found this: [Customizing QTreeView](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview)

Comment: @Thomas, I don't want to customize it. I am hiding it with QTreeWidget::setRootIsDecorated(false) and have implemented my own widget that does it. I have placed that widget on the QTreeWidgetItem with setItemWidget. Everything works, except that it acts like a button.

Comment: Why would you do that? What can't you achieve as it is?

Comment: @Thomas, it adds extra indentation, which I do not like. Also, it doesn't work well on Mac OS, requires a double-click instead of a single-click for expand/collapse. My implementation works pretty well actually, except the look-and-feel of it. Which is why I was thinking if someone is familiar with the Qt source code, they can tell me exactly what control they are using. Could be a checkbox actually, I don't know.

Comment: AFAIK its not a control, it's just drawn. [This](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/tests/auto/widgets/itemviews/qtreewidget/tst_qtreewidget.cpp.html#3377), as I am reading it, supports that assumption.

Comment: @Thomas, it has to be drawn on top of something...

Comment: It used to be the widget of the tree.